# Time complexity of 'if' with multiple conditions

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I'm confused whether the time complexities of these two codes are same or different.

code1

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

bool check(int a[])
{
  if(a[0]==1 && a[1]==1 && a[2]==1 && a[3]==1 && a[4]==1 && a[5]==1 && a[6]==1)
        return true;
   return false;
}

int main()
{
    int a[7] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
    if(check(a))
       cout<<"yes"<<endl;
    else
       cout<<"no"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

code 2

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

bool check(int a[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]!=1)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int a[7] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
    if(check(a))
       cout<<"yes"<<endl;
    else
       cout<<"no"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

when I checked it online at http://www.lizard.ws it showed that code 2 has less time complexity than code 1. If true why? please someone give me the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you're doing the same kind of thing for every item in the input once. 
if..else is just one normal statement you do to each item once. It does neither increase nor decrease the runtime/complexity. Your algorithm is O(1).
 If as per lizard.ws 2 code is efficient it might be taking the factor that everytime in code 1 u have to check all the condition despite of any single while in code 2 ur checking only one

Comment: What do you mean with `in code 1 u have to check all the condition despite of any single`? If `a[0]==1` is `false` none of the following has to be checked. In both the  cases you will only check until the first comparison is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Time complexities of both examples are the same. Especially since you don't have any variable number of elements, but fixed number. Since it's a fixed number, the time comlexity is O(1), but if the `numElements` (which is hardcoded at 7) were variable, the time complexity would be O(n).

Comment: But in the website it says the complexity of code 2 is less than code 1.

Comment: I haven't used that webiste, but don't take its word for granted. You can try submitting tests for bigger `numElemenst`, e.g. 100000. The worst case for both examples is the same and there is no doubt: in the worst case they both check each element in array once